# Equivalent of varchar(max) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, varchar

What is the equivalent of varchar(max) in MySQL?

Answer (score 238, accepted):

The max length of a varchar is subject to the max row size in MySQL, which is 64KB (not counting BLOBs):

```
VARCHAR(65535)
```

However, note that the limit is lower if you use a multi-byte character set:

```
VARCHAR(21844) CHARACTER SET utf8
```

---

Here are some examples:

The maximum row size is 65535, but a varchar also includes a byte or two to encode the length of a given string. So you actually can't declare a varchar of the maximum row size, even if it's the only column in the table.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo ( v VARCHAR(65534) );
ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

But if we try decreasing lengths, we find the greatest length that works:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo ( v VARCHAR(65532) );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Now if we try to use a multibyte charset at the table level, we find that it counts each character as multiple bytes. UTF8 strings don't *necessarily* use multiple bytes per string, but MySQL can't assume you'll restrict all your future inserts to single-byte characters.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo ( v VARCHAR(65532) ) CHARSET=utf8;
ERROR 1074 (42000): Column length too big for column 'v' (max = 21845); use BLOB or TEXT instead
```

In spite of what the last error told us, InnoDB still doesn't like a length of 21845.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo ( v VARCHAR(21845) ) CHARSET=utf8;
ERROR 1118 (42000): Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 65535. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs
```

This makes perfect sense, if you calculate that 21845*3 = 65535, which wouldn't have worked anyway. Whereas 21844*3 = 65532, which does work.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo ( v VARCHAR(21844) ) CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.32 sec)
```

Comment: I'd also suggest using TEXT

Comment: @AdnanShammout: Sure, unless you want to declare a `DEFAULT` value for the column.  Can't do that with TEXT or BLOB types.

Comment: Will using Text give you more than 65535 length?

Comment: @DanW, `TEXT` length limit is 64K.  `MEDIUMTEXT` length limit is 16M.  `LONGTEXT` length limit is 4G.

Comment: The biggest problem with this is that if you create a column of that size, you can only have that **one** column in your table. The *MAX* row size in MySql is 64k, so if you have a 64k column, that's all you get. This same constraint does not apply to Sql Server's `varchar(max)` column type.

Comment: @joshperry, yes but TEXT/BLOB columns count only a small amount (9-12 bytes) toward that 64KB row size limit, so if you need a large VARCHAR as well as a number of other columns, it's better to use TEXT.

Comment: What if the table is already set to use utf8? Does that mean the max is `VARCHAR(21844)`?

Comment: @2rs2ts, yes, if the default charset at the database or table level is utf8, then you get an error if you try to declare any varchar longer than 21844. I'll edit the answer above to show an example.

Answer (score 88):

### TL;DR

MySQL does not have an equivalent concept of `varchar(max)`, this is a MS SQL Server feature.

---

#### What is VARCHAR(max)?

`varchar(max)` is a feature of Microsoft SQL Server.

The amount of data that a column could store in Microsoft SQL server versions prior to version 2005 was limited to 8KB.  In order to store more than 8KB you would have to use `TEXT`, `NTEXT`, or `BLOB` columns types, these column types stored their data as a collection of 8K pages separate from the table data pages; they supported storing up to 2GB per row.

The big caveat to these column types was that they usually required special functions and statements to access and modify the data (e.g. `READTEXT`, `WRITETEXT`, and `UPDATETEXT`)

In SQL Server 2005, `varchar(max)` was introduced to unify the data and queries used to retrieve and modify data in large columns.  The data for `varchar(max)` columns is stored inline with the table data pages.

As the data in the MAX column fills an 8KB data page an overflow page is allocated and the previous page points to it forming a linked list. Unlike `TEXT`, `NTEXT`, and `BLOB` the `varchar(max)` column type supports all the same query semantics as other column types.

So `varchar(MAX)` really means `varchar(AS_MUCH_AS_I_WANT_TO_STUFF_IN_HERE_JUST_KEEP_GROWING)` and not `varchar(MAX_SIZE_OF_A_COLUMN)`.

#### MySQL does not have an equivalent idiom.

In order to get the same amount of storage as a `varchar(max)` in MySQL you would still need to resort to a `BLOB` column type. [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20081224081815/http://www.dreamwerx.net/phpforum/?id=1) discusses a very effective method of storing large amounts of data in MySQL efficiently.

Comment: This has more to do with SQL Server than MySQL.

Comment: @njk Yes, but in order to explain what the "equivalent" in MySql (or the lack of an equivalent in this case) necessitated describing exactly what `varchar(max)` **really** means.

Answer (score 32):

The max length of a varchar is

65535

divided by the max byte length of a character in the character set the column is set to (e.g. utf8=3 bytes, ucs2=2, latin1=1).

minus 2 bytes to store the length

minus the length of all the other columns

minus 1 byte for every 8 columns that are nullable. If your column is null/not null this gets stored as one bit in a byte/bytes called the null mask, 1 bit per column that is nullable.

Comment: I like the format of your answer but it seems to be missing some useful information that the top answer provides regarding charsets and stuff

Answer (score 10):

#### For MS SQL Server:

```sql
ALTER TABLE prg_ar_report_colors
ADD Text_Color_Code VARCHAR(max);
```

#### For MySQL:

```sql
ALTER TABLE prg_ar_report_colors
ADD Text_Color_Code LONGTEXT;
```

### For Oracle Database:

```sql
ALTER TABLE prg_ar_report_colors
ADD Text_Color_Code CLOB;
```

Comment: note that longtext, text and blob are stored differently than varchar. varchar is stored with the other fields, while text is stored on a separate file in the server. it has pros and cons so careful which one to choose

Answer (score 3):

Mysql Converting column  from VARCHAR to TEXT when under limit size!!!

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE varchars1(ch3 varchar(6),ch1 varchar(3),ch varchar(4000000))
;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                     |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1246 | Converting column 'ch' from VARCHAR to TEXT |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```