# What length should I give to a MYSQL VARCHAR field that stores a signature in JSON?

Tags: mysql, json, digital-signature, varchar

I'm trying to store signatures in a database. I'm using a the signature pad plugin ([signaturePad](http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/)) which converts from `canvas` to `JSON` and now want to store the signature in `MySQL`.

I'm using a `VARCHAR` field, but I'm not sure which length I should allow. I tried several times and usually end up with a string between 2000 and 3000 characters.

**Question:**
What should I use for field length in MYSQL? I don't know how the `CANVAS=>JSON` conversion is done, so maybe someone can give me a pointer on what to expect?

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't see http://thomasjbradley.ca/articles/saving-signatures-php-mysql/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use `VARCHAR`, I would use `TEXT`. You may sacrifice performance in doing this, but you won't have to worry about size constraints.

Edit:

Also, the maximum of `VARCHAR` is `VARCHAR(65535`).  Just making a note there..

Comment: I can set `text` to emptry string in case no signature is supplied, can I?

Comment: Yes, you can submit '' or NULL and nothing will break

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `VARCHAR`. Use `TEXT`.

Outlined in [the docs for the signaturePad plugin](http://thomasjbradley.ca/articles/saving-signatures-php-mysql/)

Answer (score 2):

probably better off using one of the TEXT datatypes.

```
TINYTEXT    256 bytes    
TEXT    65,535 bytes    ~64kb
MEDIUMTEXT   16,777,215 bytes   ~16MB
LONGTEXT    4,294,967,295 bytes ~4GB
```

It also depends on your version of MySQL.

see: [Is a VARCHAR(20000) valid in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303476/is-a-varchar20000-valid-in-mysql)