# Hibernate not recognizing column length in script. Its using default one and giving Data too long for column error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-data

I am using scripts to generate tables instead of hibernate auto generate. There is a varchar column with length 5000

```
create table my_code (
    cc_id bigint not null auto_increment unique,
    description varchar(5000),
    primary key (cc_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

In my class i have a description field:

```
@Column(name = "description", length=5000)
private String description;
```

But when i insert a field with length 300 it throws:

> Data truncation: Data too long for column 'description' at row 1

It accepts anything below 255 which is the default. Why is it not picking up length 5000?

Comment: Its better to use type of text if  you have a long text to store also see this thread [*Is a VARCHAR(20000) valid in MySQL?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1303476/is-a-varchar20000-valid-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to another table. We have an audit table with field 'description' also. Once i increased the size of the audit table description field the error went away. Unfortunately the error thrown by hibernate did not state on which table the error was thrown and i assumed it was on the regular table.