# MySQL stored procedure that accepts string with multiple parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure which accepts all the values in the IN parameter as a single string.

```
DELETE FROM object 
WHERE Type NOT IN 
    ('ListGrid',
     'TextField',
     'SpinBox',
     'MenuButton',
     'ListGrid',
     'RadioButton',
     'DropDown',
     'PopUp',
     'Element',
     'Checkbox',
     'TreeDropDown',
     'TblColumn',
     'Button',
     'Link',
     'Filter',
     'TblRow',
     'GridRow',
     'Popup')
```

This is an example of one I've tried but it does not work.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteObjectTypes(IN p_type VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
SET @query = CONCAT ('DELETE FROM object WHERE Type NOT IN (',p_type,')');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

I get the following error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''List)' at line 1
```

When running this query:

```
CALL deleteObjectTypes("'ListGrid1','TextField1','SpinBox1','MenuButton1','ListGrid2','TextField2','SpinBox2','MenuButton2','ListGrid3','TextField3','SpinBox3','MenuButton3','ListGrid4','TextField4','SpinBox4','MenuButton4','ListGrid5','TextField5','SpinBox5','MenuButton5','ListGrid6','TextField6','SpinBox6','MenuButton6'")
```

Comment: do you receive an error when you run this?

Comment: the error doesn't match any part of the code you have supplied so far. but it looks like you might have an extra `'` in there

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to change the VARCHAR size to it's maximum value (or a lower significant value).

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteObjectTypes(IN p_type VARCHAR(65535))
BEGIN
    SET @query = CONCAT ('DELETE FROM object WHERE Type NOT IN (',p_type,')');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

However, note that the limit is lower if you use a multi-byte character set:

```
VARCHAR(21844) CHARACTER SET utf8
```

As seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332798/equivalent-of-varcharmax-in-mysql).

Comment: It doesn't work after 255 characters is there any way around this?

Comment: very useful for executing sql via String, instead of direct query. I never knew how to execute with string of sql query.

Comment: @Lin Yes it can be very practical if you need to dynamicaly build your query from within the database.

Answer (score 2):

(sorry i cannot add comments too low reputation) 
Your procedure looks ok, maybe the problem is somewhere else? note that we have defined as a varchar 255 characters and the example you provided more than this number (291 characters)

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: does it give you an error about variable size when you run the stored procedure? I don't think that the Variable size is the issue, but i could be wrong

Comment: When I run it with 255 characters it works, when I run it with 256 it doesn't.

Comment: yes, its easy define more varchar lenght like Francis wrote ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should give this a try (shortened example):

```
DELETE 
FROM 
  object 
WHERE 
  NOT FIND_IN_SET( Type, 'ListGrid,TextField,SpinBox,MenuButton,ListGrid' );
```

and with stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteObjectTypes(IN p_type VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
  DELETE 
  FROM 
    object 
  WHERE 
    NOT FIND_IN_SET( Type, p_type );
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

---

```
CALL deleteObjectTypes( 'ListGrid1,TextField1,SpinBox1,MenuButton1,ListGrid2,TextField2,SpinBox2,MenuButton2,ListGrid3,TextField3,SpinBox3,MenuButton3,ListGrid4,TextField4,SpinBox4,MenuButton4,ListGrid5,TextField5,SpinBox5,MenuButton5,ListGrid6,TextField6,SpinBox6,MenuButton6' );
```

Comment: they have said that the issue resides in a Variable limit being reached

Comment: @Malachi thanx for downvoting, but you will not get an error with my solution, even with the demo data (the string contains 251 characters). I gave a working and simple and `injection-safe` solution

Comment: I know this is a very old thread, but its worth mentioning that whilst this does work, its extremely slow due to the fact that FIND_IN_SET doesn't use indexes... So be careful if adding this early on in a project, it'll become more and more of a bottleneck if you use this solution.