# Unknown syntax error in MySQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I am using below CREATE TABLE statement

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
`uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
`json` varchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
);
```

However I keep getting this error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 
>       'MAX) NOT NULL,
>               PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
>               )' at line 3

Makes no sense to me.

Comment: max is a reserved word. how about theMax...no how about a number

Comment: even without (MAX) i get the error.

Comment: varchar(60000) ?, varchar(255) ?

Comment: that worked, however is converting the row `json` from varchar to text.

Comment: sorry i was messing with 60000 once on a dif server to check max but that high i would Text for purposes mainly FULLTEXT search. typically it is like 100 or 255  (<1001)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MAX is not suported for this use, it is reserved for the MAX  function. Use the equivalent number instead, check this out: [Equivalent of varchar(max) in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332798/equivalent-of-varcharmax-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you. MAX is reserved keyword. Specify exact number of varchar instead of max. However, varchar(MAX) will work in SQL SERVER 2005+.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  uuid varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  json varchar(21808) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (uuid)
);
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23d6d)

Answer (score 1):

**MAX()** is a function in MySql,So if you want to declare the size to the max.please refer the below example.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
`uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
`json` varchar(65535) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`uuid`)
);
```

and  if you calculate that 21845*3 = 65535, which wouldn't have worked anyway. 
 Whereas 21844*3 = 65532, which does work.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE foo ( v VARCHAR(21844) ) CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.32 sec)
```