# SQL VARCHAR(MAX) wont run

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add a column with VARCHAR(MAX) to a mySQL table, and i believe the syntax is correct, it's just not going through?

here is my code:

```
ALTER TABLE content ADD contents VARCHAR(MAX);
```

It says there is a problem with the MAX part of the code, even though I believe its correct, any help would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MySQL` doesn't support the `MAX` operation. See here: [Equivalent of varchar(max) in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332798/equivalent-of-varcharmax-in-mysql)

You can use:
`VARCHAR(65535)`, but remember that a few bytes are probably needed for the server to stored data, so something like:
`VARCHAR(65000)` is safe.